# Fluid Pressures at the End of the Pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

Consider the very standard pipe problem used to calculate the force required to hold a pipe with a bend that has some fluid flowing through it, as shown in the image.

[image]

We use Newton's second law of motion to calculate the external force required. As in,
$$\sum F_x = B_x +P_1 A_1 - P_2A_2\cos \theta $$
where $B_x$ is the horizontal force of the bracket.

However, why is there pressure acting *into* the control volume at the right end of the pipe? How do you explain this? 
Shouldn't the fluid flowing out generate a pressure (force) acting outward?

Comment: There is an additional force arising from the change of momentum of the fluid. (This is not an answer to your question, which is more along the lines of “pressure pushes, doesn’t pull,” just something it seems you haven’t included.)

Comment: That's because in normal circumstances the pressure is always compressive. If you think of fluid inside the control volume as one single fluid body, then the fluid outside the control volume is compressing it from all sides.

Comment: When you learned about Newton's third law, didn't they teach you that, in a force balance, you only include the forces acting on the object being considered, not the reaction pair force it exerts on other objects?